# Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion

Tags: homebrew, qt5.5

Followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macos-high-sierra-1013-macos-sierra-1012-el-capitan-1011-and-yosemite-1010) in installing qt5.5 on a macOS version 10.13.6 High Sierra. Failed when trying to `brew install qt@5.5` giving me an error below:

```
Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion
```

Versions:

- brew
  Homebrew 2.0.0
  Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 175af; last commit 2019-02-02)
  Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 05a81; last commit 2019-02-02)
- macOS version 10.13.6 High Sierra

any help?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Referring to the [tutorial](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macos-high-sierra-1013-macos-sierra-1012-el-capitan-1011-and-yosemite-1010), the following steps are executed to install qt@5.5

```
brew update
cd $( brew --prefix )/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core

# below is the last commit containing qt@5.5 with homebrew
git checkout 9ba3d6ef8891e5c15dbdc9333f857b13711d4e97 Formula/qt@5.5.rb

# here is where the error occurs
brew install qt@5.5
```

**Solution**

turns out line 25 of qt@5.5.rb formula file checked out in the command ( as seen in the [referred tutorial](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macos-high-sierra-1013-macos-sierra-1012-el-capitan-1011-and-yosemite-1010))

```
git checkout 9ba3d6ef8891e5c15dbdc9333f857b13711d4e97 Formula/qt@5.5.rb
```

is causing this problem. commenting it out fixes the issue

[image]

Comment: @ChrisHough what is the error you see when you run `brew install qt@5.5` after commenting out line 25 of the file mentioned above?

Comment: I was finding it difficult to find the actual file.

On my device, it is located in `/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/.brew` and I had to comment out line #69

Comment: @AshNaz87 .brew is empty for me, is there another location?

Comment: @ChrisHough .brew is a dot directory. What do you get hit `ls -a` (in the qt@5.5 directory)?

Comment: @AshNaz87 I was able to find it at /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/qt@5.5.rb however, I have noticed this disappear when I run brew update and brew upgrade

Comment: /usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/.brew/qt@5.5.rb Look for depends_on - Line 16 for me

Comment: This works for me too, but as @ChrisHough mentioned, the problem reoccurs after running brew update.