# How to resolve capybara-webkit gem installation error in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

**An error occurred while installing `capybara-webkit (1.15.1)`, and Bundler
cannot continue**

In my Ruby on Rails Project, trying to do bundle install, which is failing due to this `capybara-webkit gem`

```
My Complete Version Details:

Mac version                  macOS Catalina Version 10.15.1
rvm -v                       rvm 1.29.9
ruby -v                      2.1.4p265
Required capybara-webkit     1.15.1
Required rails version       4.1.4
Qt Version                   5.5.1
bundler --version            1.17.2

qmake -v 
QMake version 3.0 Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5.5/5.5.1_1/lib

gcc --version 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

g++ --version 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Here are few links that I followed

1) [Mac OS 10.14 Mojave + qt5.5 + gem capybara-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661109/mac-os-10-14-mojave-qt5-5-gem-capybara-webkit)

2) https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macOS-catalina-1015

3) https://wilsonmar.github.io/xcode/

Here is the attached image
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of `bundler` do you use?

Comment: Can you please provide the complete error message from `bundler`

Comment: Does `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.15.1'` work or does it also fail?

Comment: `gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)`
 ....
`bundler --version
Bundler version 1.17.2`

Comment: Did you add `qt` to our `PATH` as suggested?

Comment: @ThomasKoppensteiner Yes I have Added Qt path in shell files(bashrc and zshrc files) as well as mentioned in the previous discussions 


`export PATH="$(brew --prefix qt@5.5)/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: The error log states, that  `xcode` is not installed properly.
Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools

Comment: Do we definitely need to install XCode, as in the official downloads, I have not installed it, as it showing as 7GB

I have installed Qt and gcc compiler